# Pandas: Get next value in column after string match

Tags: python, pandas

How does one get the *next value* in a column, *after* a string match?

```
regex = 'ABC'
row_match = df["column1"].str.match(regex, case=False)
```

I.e. how to get the value in the next row in the same column, following the one where the string `ABC` can be found?

I tried iterating over one row with `iterrows`, but I wasn't able to get it to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try using [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to get the next value.

Here is a small example :

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'e']
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df
   0
0  a
1  b
2  c
3  d
4  c
5  e
>>> df[df[0].str.match('c').shift(1).fillna(False)]
   0
3  d
5  e
```

I use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to replace the `NaN` in the first row.

Comment: Thanks – but am I right in my interpretation that this shifts *all* the index values in the DataFrame? I would like to keep the DataFrame intact as-is, while getting the next value in the same column.

Comment: Since I call `shift` on `df[0].str.match('c')`, the only values that are actually offset are the Booleans corresponding to the `match` result. The DataFrame itself is left unchanged. Try typing `df[0].str.match('c')` and `df[0].str.match('c').shift(1)` in your prompt to understand the behavior.